# append or remove file from tar and tar.gz

Tags: tar, gzip, bzip2

I want to append files to `foo.tar`:

```
tar -rvf foo.tar IMG_1807.MOV
```

this works, but when I want to remove files:

```
tar -dvf foo.tar IMG_1807.MOV
```

doesn't work. It shows the output:

```
Terminal:~/Desktop$ tar -dvf foo.tar IMG_1807.MOV 
IMG_1807.MOV
Terminal:~/Desktop$ tar -tvf foo.tar
-rw-rw-r-- user/user    33084363 2018-12-19 03:02 IMG_1807.MOV
```

but doesn't delete anything. What should I do?

Second, how can I add or remove files from `file.tar.gz` or `file.tar.bz2` or `file.tar.xz`? Is there any command or I should always untar and tar again?

---

Edit:

Third: How to extract a specific file from a zipped file? Or how to extract from tar in a specific location? This did NOT work:

```
 tar -xvf foo.tar IMG_1807.MOV -C /path/to/destination
```

Comment: please next time ask separate questions as it's easier to answer and easier to find for others.

Comment: @RoVo questions where related together, but next time OK. Tnx for recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

`-d` is not *delete* but *diff*.

From `man tar`:

> ```
>  -d, --diff, --compare
>        find differences between archive and file system
> ```

use `--delete`.

```
tar --delete -vf foo.tar IMG_1807.MOV
```

---

You cannot update a `tar.gz` file, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267344/how-can-i-update-a-tar-gz-file) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/add-update-a-file-to-an-existing-tar-gz-archive).

---

Regarding your question how to extract to specific location:

You must follow the correct command line order. `-C` as an *option* goes before `[pathname]`. See `man tar` for more information. The following works:

```bsh
tar -xvf foo.tar -C /path/to/destination IMG_1807.MOV
```