# tar of a directory with final check for changes

Tags: 18.04, ext4, tar

is there a way to use tar to pack a directory and check the source data for changes after taring?

Well I want to pack a folder. But it can happen that the content of the folder is changed during the packing process. I need a way for tar to check if the source files have changed after the archive has been created. If so, the packed files should be overwritten with the new source files

Comment: Do [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/267362/1001338) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/267362/1001338) answer your question ? You can update the tar archive after you've created it . It's much simpler.

Comment: yesss, this could work thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update just the contents of the existing files and also newer files (but not deleting the files from the archive which are no longer in the current directory ,because that will give you the error `No such file or directory` trying to update the archive ) , you can use the `diff` feature as @Niels Tolstrup mentioned and then use `--update` or simply `-u` to update the archive contents :

```
tar -uf tarfile.tar `tar --diff --file tarfile.tar | awk ' { print $1 } ' | cut -d: -f1`
```

**Note :** Tar `update` will make many duplicate entries in the tar file which you can see them via `tar --list --file tarfile.tar` but that's not a problem when you extract the files.

Comment: thats nice, is there a way or a hack to do that with compressed archives?

Comment: @Rudi For zip files it's quite [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799569/11970791) .For xz and gzip files you have to first [gunzip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gunzip) or [unxz](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unxz) them ( which might be not suitable for you because you mentioned you have not enough disk space available) , then update the contents using the above method and finally recompress them.

Comment: zip sounds an alternative, but if i try to append file to an exist zip, zip repack the whole archive. That mean, zip need disk space for two archives in zip process

Comment: @Rudi So what about gzip or xz ? Do they have the same problem ?

Comment: i cant append files to an compressed tgz :( but i need it compressed. xz I have not yet examined, i will do it

Comment: nope, no way. xz is slow as underground. I have tried 7z with the update option, but the same there. The archive will repacked completely..

I need an compressed archive where i can update only diffs to the originals.. this should be possible, maybe this format should use an index, but it must be possible :(

Comment: @Rudi Tar archives are actually like a filesystem . You can easily add or remove a file or folder within them. But compressed archives are like the jpeg format.Contents are compressed as a whole. You cannot edit a jpeg file without decoding it first.So I don't think it's possible to do the same with compressed archives. If you found a solution for it , I'm glad to hear.

Answer (score 2):

you could rsync the directory to a temporary place, then you keep checking with rsync until there are no changes, and finally you make your tar file.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have enough disk space available, so it is important for me to update the archive by myself

Comment: tar has a diff option, have you tried it.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi wrote that i should use the -u option. i believe that could work for my case